# Can pass HTML Special character as a og: description?

Tags: asp.net, facebook-c#-sdk, visual-web-developer

I giving a support for my friend website. In that site they use Regex pattern for filter tags and HTML special characters. Case of that quote and others symbols are missing when it comes as a special character (ex:- &rsquo &lsquo).

So do we need to remove HTML special character from og:description property field ?

Comment: Have your checked [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I can't change any thing because it is on live. Before changing I need to get Idea. Because I searched a lot but I can't find anything similar.

Comment: No need to remove special characters in content when passing the value of og:description

Comment: शेखर
 - broken link